# Demonstratives and adverbs of place: perspective in respect to speaker, interlocutor and a third person

Tags: pronoms, adverbes, indications-de-lieu

I have recently learned that Portuguese demonstratives and adverbs of place strictly distinguish position near the speaker, the interlocutor and a third person:

- *este/a/es/as* = this, near me; *aqui*=here, near me
- *esse/a/es/as* = this/that, near your; *aí*=there, near you
- *aquele/a/es/as* = that, near him/her/it; *alí*= over there, near him/her/it

As far as I can judge, French is more flexible in this sense, with *-ci/-là* distinguishing the object that is closer or further from the speaker, with the corresponding adverbs being *ici/là* and *là-bas*. However, I have never encountered a clear discussion of these points and would appreciate a clarification.