# Attacher dimanche avec lundi

Tags: locutions, informatique, comparaison-de-langues, locutions-comparatives

> ***boutonner dimanche avec lundi***
> Se tromper d’un cran en boutonnant un vêtement, de sorte qu’un côté est plus haut que l’autre. Toutes les variantes existent (boutonner lundi avec mardi, etc.).

([voir ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/boutonner_dimanche_avec_lundi))

Est-ce que le choix de jours de la semaine dans cette locution correspond aux boutons mal boutonnés, selon l'ordre numerique de jours (par exemple - dimanche - le premier, lundi - le deuxième, etc.) ? Si je me trompe de deux crans, doit je dire *dimanche avec mardi*, de trois crans - *dimanche avec mercredi* etc.?

**Remark:** Admettons que c'est une question un peu ironique, mais on n'est jamais sur, quand on parle d'une langue étrangere - parfois elles sont très precises (voir par exemple [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/51039/9870) et [ici](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9412/11666)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le décalage entre les jours choisis correspond certainement au décalage entre les boutons et les boutonnières, donc *dimanche avec lundi* indique qu'on s'est trompé d'un cran, alors que par exemple *jeudi avec dimanche* indique un décalage de trois boutons.

Le choix des jours est en revanche arbitraire, d'autant plus qu'en France, le premier jour de la semaine est généralement considéré comme étant le lundi et pas le dimanche. *Boutonner dimanche avec lundi*, *lundi avec mardi* ou *mardi avec lundi*<sup>1</sup> sont donc tous trois équivalents.

> *Sa vêture est un peu hasardeuse, elle a boutonné jeudi avec dimanche, son pantalon de tergal est à l’envers, l'étiquette pend comme la langue d’un chien.*
> Guillaume Le Touze, *Attraction*, 2005.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Peut-être que dans ce dernier cas, le deuxième bouton pourrait être placé dans la première boutonnière alors que dans le cas du *lundi avec mardi*, ce serait l'inverse.</sub>